# UIButton inside UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton, uitableview

I have a `UIButton` that is created inside of each table cell. I want to hook up a touch event like so:

```
[imageButton addTarget:self
                action:@selector(startVote:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I want to pass data about the current row (the id of the object for that row) to the startVote method. Is there a method that I am missing to do this or am I breaking some best practice. This seems like a very normal thing to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have some sort of `NSArray` with the data that gets passed on to the buttons in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Try this in `startVote`:

```
- (void)startVote:(id)sender {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDictionary *myData = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}
```

EDIT:

If for some reason the row is not selected, you can assign a unique `tag` to every button upon creation and then:

```
- (void)startVote:(id)sender {
    int myTag = [(UIButton *)sender tag];
    NSDictionary *myData = [myArray objectAtIndex:myTag];
}
```

Maybe you would do some sort of operation with the `tag` so it can be used as an index (I add a certain amount to every `tag` so it will not conflict with "automatic" tagging used by the OS.

Comment: The row will not be selected. When the button is tapped, the row does not get selected.

Comment: edited to reflect the current need with a "cheesy" but working solution

Answer (score 2):

The `UITableViewCell` doesn't know, out of the box, what row it's displaying in the table. Remember, the intent is that the same cell instances are re-used all over the table to display its data. That said, your `UITableViewController` is responsible for setting up the cells and passing them to the system (and has the index path, of course). You could, at that point, do something like:

- Assuming it's a custom cell class, set a property on the cell instance to identify what row it's displaying, and which your button can later use.
- If you're putting these buttons in the cells as their accessory views, take a look at the table delegate's [`tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:) method.
- If it's a one-section table, you could do something really cheesy like store the row index in the button's `tag` property. Your `startVote:` method is passed the button, and could then extract its tag.

Comment: The custom cell property to save its current row index is the best approach I have heard so far.